# Why is my test database empty before and after running rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unit-testing

Although most people want their database empty between runs of a unit/functional test, I'm debugging a problem and find it inconvenient and rather surprising that my test database is empty before and after running a test.  Even if I put something in the setup and teardown to print out the size of a particular table, it is always 0 on setup, and sometimes more than 0 on teardown.

What is doing this for me?  I have no fixtures (I have commented out the default "fixtures :all" in test_helper) and I am using simple unit/functional tests that extend ActiveSupport::TestCase (no RSpec or anything like that).  I have not added much/any custom configuration/setup since generating the rails project.

I am running Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.8.7.

All ideas welcome!

Comment: It would be helpful to see some actual code, rather than just a description of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable this behavior by setting `use_transactional_fixtures` to `false`:

```
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  Looks like this has been in since Rails 1.0 from a quick internet search.  Odd then that I found lots of hits on how to delete data between runs if it is the default?...  Many thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests need to have known, fresh state, which is why the DB gets cleared.

Preventing test db from getting wiped is pretty easy w/ RSpec.  Not sure how you'd do it in the context of Rails' built-in Test::Unit stuff, but one thing you might want to consider if this is just for quick debugging purposes is simply using the logger and tailing the test log:

```
Rails.logger.info "\n\nThe value of foo is #{foo}\n\n"
```

That will drop into test.log and will put a couple line breaks on each side to make it easy for you to see it in the midst of all the other stuff there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am already debugging with print statements, and still cannot work out what is going wrong.  There seems to be some database inconsistency that only happens occasionally when I run the tests from autotest.  Running the test repeatedly from the command line via "ruby -Itest ..." always works fine.  I think it's something to do with the setup of a parent class being run more than once.

Comment: I added a few more print statements (just added "puts ..." in various places) and found that it was indeed because I had class X < Y and had "setup do" in both X and Y.  Sometimes X.setup was run twice.  I guess that must be some quirk of the way setup works?  Anyway, I'd still be interested to know if clearing the DB between runs is a new standard part of Rails 3.x or something...

Comment: Clearing the DB between runs has been part of Rails for as long as I've been using it (since 1.3x).  Sounds like you might be able to redo your class setup a bit and still be in business...?  :-)

Comment: Indeed, I fixed my setup.  I was kind of assuming one was being done before the other.  I only need one on reflection so I've deleted the other.